# Facebook extended permission dialog cut-off - not showing allow/disallow button

Tags: javascript, facebook

Using js inside an iframe to ask for extended permissions:

FB.ensureInit(function() {
            FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("publish_stream", submit_post);
        });

the dialog pops up, but the lower half of the dialog is hidden and the user can't possibly click allow (or disallow for that matter)

has anyone seen this? what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're fixing it now:

> Permission dialog issues, Today, 25 February at 09:20We're currently working to resolve an issue that is causing permission dialogs to be cut off. We apologize for the inconvenience and expect to have a fix out today. You can follow bug 5889 for updates from our engineering team.

See http://developers.facebook.com/live_status.php